# How do I activate voice dial outside the U.S.?

Tags: voice-command

I just bought a Xperia PLAY running Android 2.3.3, and seems like the only way to use voice dial is through the Google Search app, which is capable of voice dialing, voice texting, etc., at least according to the [YouTube demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gGbYVvU0Z5s). However, it looks like those services are only available in the U.S., according to the comments.

Poking around the services running in my phone, there's a "Voice Dial" app running (the icon is something like a phone mic), but it doesn't show in my installed apps and I don't know how to activate it... any ideas?

[Here's](http://cache5.groovypost.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/image_33.png) an image of the Voice Dialer app icon.

Comment: Your image is 404.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try long-pressing the `Search` button.  It should be tied to Voice Search by default.  Then say *"dial xxx"*, where "xxx" is either a phone number (with the area code) or name of a contact from your phonebook.

Here are all the voice actions you can perform with the Voice Search app: http://www.google.com/mobile/voice-actions/

**Note:**
According to Google's last [blog post](http://googlemobile.blogspot.com/2010/08/just-speak-it-introducing-voice-actions.html) on the subject, voice actions via this app only work in English language.  You might need to change your phone's locale to "US" or "UK" in order to get this to work.

Comment: Great! it shows the voice dialer, but when I say something, instead of dialing it does a google search for the words I said

Comment: Are you saying the word "Dial" before the number or "Call" before the person's name?

Comment: I just changed the language to US English, and it worked... It was previously in spanish (forgot to add that part in my original post).
So I guess it doesn't support spanish yet?

Comment: Yes, according to Google's last blog post on this subject, it only works in English: http://googlemobile.blogspot.com/2010/08/just-speak-it-introducing-voice-actions.html

Comment: :( I thought that it was a very basic functionality of a phone, as many of my previous phones had this (in spanish)